# Quick Sort Implementation using python

Tags: python-3.x, quicksort

```
def partition(lst, low,high, pivot,col):

    lst[high],lst[pivot] = lst[pivot],lst[high]
    pivot = high
    i = low
    while i +1 <pivot:
        if lst[i][col] > lst[pivot][col]:
            lst[pivot], lst[pivot-1] = lst[pivot-1], lst[pivot]
            lst[i],lst[pivot] = lst[pivot],lst[i]
            pivot -= 1
        else:
            i +=1
    if lst[i][col] > lst[pivot][col]:
        lst[i],lst[pivot] = lst[pivot],lst[i]
        pivot -= 1
    return pivot

def quick(lst,low,high,col,ascending):
    if low >= high:
        return
    else:
        #print(low,high)
        pivot = random.randint(low,high)
        #print(pivot)
        part_point = partition(lst,low,high,pivot,col)
        print(part_point,high)
        quick(lst,low,part_point-1,col,ascending)
        quick(lst,part_point+1, high,col, ascending)
```

I am learning algorithms using Python, here is my implementation of the quicksort. While it is working well for certain cases, it exceeds the recursion depth on most cases. I think there is some error in my execution, which I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not accustomed to seeing the pivot change in the partition method. Usually the pivot is set as left element in the array. It can be optionally switched with a random element a[k] where low <= k <= high. Usually the partition method uses two variables, i and j, where i is the counter as partition passes left-to-right through the array and j shows the largest element a[j] such that a[j] <= pivot. The value at a[j] gets swapped with a[low] at the end of the partition function and the function returns j.

Sedgewick and Wayne have a wonder chapter on their website on this subject: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/